# Error: Cannot find module 'ErrorUtils' from 'env.js'

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to use jest with react-native got stuck with this error.

```
Runtime Error
Error: Cannot find module 'ErrorUtils' from 'env.js'
```

Here's my jest key for package.json

```
"jest": {
  "scriptPreprocessor": "node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/preprocessor.js",
  "setupEnvScriptFile": "node_modules/react-native/jestSupport/env.js",
  "testDirectoryName": "__jest__"
}
```

versions:

```
react-native: 0.24.0
jest-cli: 12.0.2
babel-jest: 12.0.2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Same, react-native v0.24, jest v12.

I have reported an issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/974

To hotfix this, you should remove that line (see in issue)

1. Copy `node_modules/jestSupport` to your project
2. edit `jestSupport/env.js`
3. comment out line `jest.setMock('ErrorUtils', require('ErrorUtils'));`
4. correct top require path from relative to node_modules. For now it's: `require.requireActual('react-native/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/babelHelpers.js');`
5. open your package.json and specify this edited env :

   `{
       // ...
       "jest": {
           "setupEnvScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jestSupport/env.js",
           // ...
       }
   }`